# Using preg_match to filter numbers

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I use preg_match to filter phone numbers which are given to me via a submit button.
I want to accept all variations of numbers which start with: `00` or `+` followed by atleast 3 didgits. For example `00123` and `+123` would be valid, `12345` would not be valid. The number can be as long as it wants and contain numerous capital A's or F's at the very end. The version i currently use seems to be kind of complicated because i try to think of every character i want to deny rather than only allowing those i want.

```
//i check if the number starts with 00 or + and has atleast 3 didgtis following that
if(preg_match("/(^00|^\+)[0-9][0-9][0-9]+/", $nummer)){

  //i then try to eliminate all characters i don't want which i can think of
  if(preg_match("/([a-z]|[B-E]|[G-Z]|\s\.)/", $nummer)){
  ->deny}//actual code is different

  else(preg_match("/([0-9]|A|F)/", $nummer)){
  ->allow}}//actual code is different
```

I know that my current preg_match does not care where my A's and F's are, as long as they are not in one of the first three positions following `00` or `+`, but i haven`t found a way to deal with that yet.
What I want to ask is, if there's a way to deny every input that comes except your matches rather than allowing everything and having to think of everything you don't want.
I would like to let nothing pass the test, except if it looks like this:

```
00123456789123 or +123456789AAAAA or 00123FFFFFFFFFF or +123AAAAAAFFA
```

and so on...

Comment: Please choose meaningful titles for your questions. Your title should clearly indicate what your question is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one does the job:

```
^(?:00|\+)\d{3,}[AF]*$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^           : begining of line
  (?:       : start non capture group
    00      : literally 00
    |       : OR
    \+      : + sign
  )         : end group
  \d{3,}    : 3 or more digits
  [AF]*     : 0 or more letters A or F (change * to + if you want at least one letter)
$           : end of line
```

**In action:**

```
$tests = [
    '00123456789123',
    '+123456789AAAAA',
    '00123FFFFFFFFFF',
    '+123AAAAAAFFA',
    'ABCD',
    '123456F',
    '00123B'
];

foreach($tests as $str) {
    if(preg_match('/^(?:00|\+)\d{3,}[AF]*$/', $str)) {
        echo "$str --> Match\n";
    } else {
        echo "$str --> NO match\n";
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
00123456789123 --> Match
+123456789AAAAA --> Match
00123FFFFFFFFFF --> Match
+123AAAAAAFFA --> Match
ABCD --> NO match
123456F --> NO match
00123B --> NO match
```

Comment: Thank's, this is a perfect fit for my case.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like:

```
/^(+|00)\d{3,}[A-F]*$/
```